# Does the destructor of a class automatically deallocate memory for data members of type char *? C++

Tags: c++, destructor

Say I have the following class:

```
class A {
  public:
    A();
    ~A();
    //...some other functions

  private:
      char * data;
}
```

**Question 1:** Do I have to explicitly define the destructor as the following:

```
//destructor
A::~A() {
  delete [] data;
}
```

Or, does the compiler do that implicitly?

**Question 2:** What if I used the same constructed class in main repeatedly inside a loop, does the data member of class `A` deallocates its memory after each loop? If not, should I do it explicitly?

i.e.:

```
int main() {
    A obj;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        getData(obj); //this function will store an input 3 times inside `data`
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"Or, does the compiler do that implicitly?"_ No. _"does the class A deallocates its memory after each loop? "_ Put `A obj;` inside the loop body.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ do I have to?

Comment: @Lieft1951 Yes, otherwise will cause memory leak.

Comment: Q1: The c++ way of storing data would be to use a std::string or a std::vector<char>. They would be deallocated automatically at destruction. Raw pointers would not be deallocated.

Comment: For every `new` you need to have a `delete`. What's else to talk about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A few memory management questions involving class destructors and delete operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600229/a-few-memory-management-questions-involving-class-destructors-and-delete-operato)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The destructor would destroy its own members, sure, BUT, only the member, what it points to is none of its business. In other words, you've to manually clean up whatever you made `data` to point to. So, yes, you need to explicitly do it in the destructor.

Alternatively, instead of managing this yourself, you can use C++11's `std::unique_ptr`, in which case, the class destructor would call `std::unique_ptr`'s destructor, which would reclaim the memory you allocated. An SSCCE

```
#include <memory>

class myClass {
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> data;

public:
  myClass() : data(new int[5]{1, 21, 9, -1}) { }
};
```

You don't even need to define a destructor in this case, the default compiler-provided one would do. Read about the new [Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero).

> What if I used the same constructed class in main repeatedly inside a loop, does the data member of class A deallocates its memory after each loop? If not, should I do it explicitly?

If you've the scope of your object within the loop body, then yes, every time the variable goes out of scope (the loop ends), the data held by it would be destroyed and the next time gets re-created; this unnecessary and expensive allocation/deallocation can be avoided. You might expose a helper function, say `assign` that takes in the data you want to replace the old data with and assigns it to the objects pointed to by `data`. Now you can have `A obj` outside the loop body and every time inside the loop you need to just `assign`.

There already is a container in the standard C++ library which does this low-level task of managing the memory: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/). I wasn't sure if this is what you wanted, but thanks to Galik for bringing this up. You can use its `reserve`, `assign` and other functions to get to an elegant *and* performant solution.

Comment: Wouldn't a `std::string` or a `std::vector<char>` be more appropriate than a smart pointer?

Comment: I'm unsure of the `string` but a `vector` is perhaps appropriate; it depends on what the OP wants. See the updated answer.